# Why does ctanify not work with .cls files?

Tags: packages

I have a handful of `.sty` files and `.cls` files that I occasionally work with. They are outside the TeX directory tree. I have found a convenient way to install these files using `ctanify`, for instance

```
ctanify -d  `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` -- printout.sty
```

installs `printout.sty` in my personal tree where TeX can find it. However this technique doesn't work with `.cls` files as `ctanify` insists that I must supply an `.sty` or an `.ins`.  Is there any workaround to this problem?

Comment: When I run `ctanify`, it says `Please either list a .ins or .sty file or specify --pkgname`.  Grabbing a random `.cls` file from my TDS and giving a `pkgname` seems to work:  `ctanify --pkgname=xkeyval xkvecb.cls`.

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I run `ctanify`, it says

```
Please either list a .ins or .sty file or specify --pkgname
```

Grabbing a random `.cls` file from my TDS and giving a `pkgname` seems to work:

```
ctanify --pkgname=xkeyval xkvecb.cls
```